# How to check if a file exists in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
if exist('JaccardDistance', 'file')==1
    load('JaccardDistance');
else
    % Do things
end
```

The file JaccardDistance is in the same folder where this code is being executed. The problem is that the "else" part is always being executed, which means that it is not recognizing that the file JaccardDistance exists. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `size(dir('JaccardDistance'),1)` ?

Comment: Doesn't your filename have an extension?

Comment: Voting to close because this is essentially a typo. Please [read the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) for the functions you want to use.

Comment: @BillBokeey It does, and that's one of the errors. Did not put extension because when saving file (with 'save' function) I dont need to write the extension, but apparently, when loading I do need to say what is the extension.

Comment: Note that now this is now the first Google search result for "check if file exists Matlab'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For files you exists will return a 2 not a 1. You should also include the file extension in the check.

```
if exist('JaccardDistance.m', 'file') == 2
```

ref [matlab forum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49414-check-if-a-file-exists)
Or read the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html):

exist name returns the status of name:

- `0` name does not exist.
- `1` name is a variable in the workspace.
- `2` One of the following is true:

  - name exists on your MATLAB® search path as a file with extension .m.
  - name is the name of an ordinary file on your MATLAB search path.
  - name is the full pathname to any file.

Comment: I think as long as it is not a folder or class it should work, although not thoroughly tested

Comment: @Andres you are right. Deleted my comment because it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exist function does not return a 1, you have to use

```
if exist('JaccardDistance', 'file')
```

Depending on what the function found, a view between 1 and 8 is returned. If nothing is found, a 0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

To return 1 or 0 use

```
size(dir('JaccardDistance'),1)
```

i.e. if size(dir('JaccardDistance'),1) == 1 %//you have a file if 0 you have no file