# If statement for when CD (Change current folder) fails - Matlab

Tags: matlab

when I run this line `readPath = cd(app.myPath)` I get this Error because I do not have a value for app.myPath
`Error using cd Cannot CD to  (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).`

Therefore, how can I write an if statement that if the CD is not correct or my `app.myPath` is empty,  it will automatically assign to `app.myPath` the computer desktop folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a file exists in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092819/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB has a [`exist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) and an [`isfolder`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfolder.html) function for this.

Using `exist`:

```
if exist(app.myPath, 'dir') == 7
    % do something
else
    % do something else
end
```

Using `isfolder`:

```
if isfolder(app.myPath)
    % do something
else
    % do something else
end
```